# How to output data from a file using preg match in php

Tags: php, get

I have used this code to generate the output (file.php)

```
<?php

function getContents($str, $startDelimiter, $endDelimiter) {
  $contents = array();
  $startDelimiterLength = strlen($startDelimiter);
  $endDelimiterLength = strlen($endDelimiter);
  $startFrom = $contentStart = $contentEnd = 0;
  while (false !== ($contentStart = strpos($str, $startDelimiter, $startFrom))) {
    $contentStart += $startDelimiterLength;
    $contentEnd = strpos($str, $endDelimiter, $contentStart);
    if (false === $contentEnd) {
      break;
    }
    $contents[] = substr($str, $contentStart, $contentEnd - $contentStart);
    $startFrom = $contentEnd + $endDelimiterLength;
  }

  return $contents;
}


$sample = '
<start>One<end>
<start>Two<end>
<start>Four - 565<end>
<start>Five - 556<end>
';
$v = getContents($sample, '<start>', '<end>');

$result = preg_filter('/[0-9]+/', '($0)', $v);

foreach ($result as $value => $name) {
    echo $name;
    echo "<br>";
}




?>
```

Which actually outputs

```
Four - (565)
Five - (556)
```

Example : `127.0.0.1/file.php?username=Four` when we go to that url the number to it comes `565`.

Is there a way to achieve this with PHP ?

Comment: Please explain what the _purpose_ of this is. If it is mere data storage - then why are you choosing such a weird custom format, and not use JSON or XML for it? Parsers for those formats already exist, so you would not have to write one yourself.

Comment: I would personnaly use a regular expression instead of some PHP code with the loop. It will probably be more efficient. How big is the XML data in which you are searching? Is it possible to parse it once and convert it to a PHP array or store it in a database table 
if its really big?

Comment: Please i want to do this the way i showed above if you have another way please let me know

Comment: @mebak: As @CBroe said, is the XML forced to be like that? If yes, what do we do if an entry such as `<start>One<end>` doesn't contain any number next to it?
`<start><end>` isn't XML! It should be something like `<item>Four - 565</item>`

Comment: we don't use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as you want to stick on this non-XML data and don't give us more information about the size of the data nor the way to reply if no number is next to the searched item then you could just start off with a simple regular expression like this one.

Regular expression: `<start>Four[\s-]*(\d*)<end>`

Play arround with it here: https://regex101.com/r/p0aaGG/1
You'll have the explanation of the regular expression on *regex101.com*:

- In PHP, a regular expression must be surrounded by a starting and ending char and then some flags can be added after. Most often we use the `/` delimiter like it's the case in JavaScript. But some persons use `#` or `~`. Example:

  - `/Teddy/i` will look for the word *Teddy* but case insensitive.
  - `~Teddy~i` is exactly the same regular expression but written with another delimiter. This is why `preg_quote()` has a second parameter to give the delimiter used if its not the usual slash `/`.
- `\s` means any kind of space char.
- `[\s-]` means any kind of space char or the `-` char.
- `[\s-]*` means it can be 0 or multiple times.
- `\d` means any digit char.
- `\d*` means any digit char 0 or multiple times.
- `()` are used to capture, so that we can get it later in the `$matches` array.

Now if `<start>`, `<end>` and `Four` are parameters then you could do this in PHP:

```php
<?php

$sample = '<start>One<end>
<start>Two<end>
<start>Four - 565<end>
<start>Five - 556<end>';

function getContents($username, $startDelimiter, $endDelimiter) {
    global $sample;
    
    // The pattern (regex) looks like this: /<start>Four[\s-]*(.*?)<end>/
    $pattern = '/' .
        preg_quote($startDelimiter) .
        preg_quote($username) .
        '[\s-]*(\d*)' .
        preg_quote($endDelimiter) .
        '/';
    
    $matches = [];
    if (preg_match($pattern, $sample, $matches)) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

// Test all usernames.
$usernames = [
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Four',
    'Five',
    'unknown user'
];

foreach ($usernames as $username) {
    $result = getContents($username, '<start>', '<end>');
    echo "Result for '$username' is " . var_export($result, true) . "\n";
}
```

The result of this sample script is:

```
Result for 'One' is ''
Result for 'Two' is ''
Result for 'Four' is '565'
Result for 'Five' is '556'
Result for 'unknown user' is false
```

For @mebak:

If you just want the result then don't do the loop over the tested users and read the username from the `$_GET` or `$_POST` arrays that PHP fills for us:

```php
// Same as above and then just this:

if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
    $username = $_GET['username'];
}
elseif (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
}
else {
    die("Missing username!");
}

print getContents($username, '<start>', '<end>');
```

Comment: I want to get the user info via get or POST request

Comment: In this case just print the result!
Replace `$username` by `$_GET['username']` (or `$_POST`), call the function once and print the result. As simple as that ;-)